# How to make the equivalent of a C-style if-else statement in Erlang?

Tags: if-statement, erlang

How do I make the equivalent of a [C-style](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson2.html) if-else in Erlang?

```
 if(a == b) {
   expression1
 } else {
   expression2 
 }
```

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327860/erlang-equivalent-to-if-else).

Answer (score 33):

```
if
    a == b ->
        expr1;
    true ->
        exprElse
end
```

There is no real else in Erlang, you just match with true. More information at the [Erlang documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#6.7).

You have to pay close attention to the ';' terminator :

```
if
    a == b ->
        clauseN,
        expr1;
    cond2 ->
        clause1,
        clause2,
        expr2;
    cond3 ->
        expr3;
    true ->
        exprElse
end
```

It's not a copy-paste friendly language.

Comment: isn't the equality operator in Erlang `=:=`?

Comment: Also note that it is an error if none of the conditions match, hence the true clause as the end as a fall through.

Comment: @Tommy Erlang also has `==`, `==` means _equal to_, `=:=` means _exactly equal to_, kinda like JavaScript's `===`

Answer (score 19):

Pattern matching is one of Erlangs many strengths and it can often be used instead of if statements. It is often more readable to pattern match on function arguments or use a case expression (which also is pattern matching).

Suppose you have a function `some_function` which takes two arguments. If the arguments are equal you evaluate expression1, otherwise you evaluate expression2. This can be expressed in erlang as:

```
some_function(A, A) -> expression1;
some_function(A, B) -> expression2.
```

It is quite amazing how much you can achieve with this kind of simple pattern matching. With guard clauses you can express more complicated patterns, e.g.,

```
some_function(A, B) when A < B -> expression3.
```

Another possibility is to use a `case .. of` expression. Your particular example would translate to

```
case a == b of
    true -> expression1;
    false -> expression2
end.
```

(In this case `expression2` would always be evaluated since `a` and `b` are atoms and never equal to each other. Variables in Erlang are upper case.)

You can read more about Erlang expressions [here](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#6).

Comment: I'd also suggest using `=:=` instead of `==`. 

This is a really good answer - new erlang programmers should always use `case` until they figure out why the `if` statement should have been the `when` statement.

Answer (score 15):

```
if
    A =:= B ->
        expr1;
    true ->
        expr2
end
```

or

```
case A =:= B of
    true -> expr1;
    false -> expr2
end
```

or

```
case A of
    B -> expr1;
    _ -> expr2
end
```

or

```
  foo(A,B), ...

...
foo(X,X) -> expr1;
foo(_,_) -> expr2.
```

Answer (score 8):

Another option:

```
case a of
    b -> expr1;  %% true
    _ -> expr2   %% false
end.
```