# What is the canonical way to handle conditionals in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

I am working on simple list functions in Erlang to learn the syntax.
Everything was looking very similar to code I wrote for the Prolog version of these functions until I got to an implementation of 'intersection'.

The cleanest solution I could come up with:

```
myIntersection([],_) -> [];
myIntersection([X|Xs],Ys) ->
    UseFirst = myMember(X,Ys),
    myIntersection(UseFirst,X,Xs,Ys).

myIntersection(true,X,Xs,Ys) ->
    [X|myIntersection(Xs,Ys)];
myIntersection(_,_,Xs,Ys) ->
    myIntersection(Xs,Ys).
```

To me, this feels slightly like a hack. Is there a more canonical way to handle this? By 'canonical', I mean an implementation true to the spirit of what Erlang's design.

Note: the essence of this question is **conditional handling of user-defined predicate functions**. I am *not* asking for someone to point me to a library function. Thanks!

Comment: I'd use `if` (or `case`): https://stackoverflow.com/a/4330106/320615. E.g. `if myMember(X, Ys) -> [X|myIntersection(Xs,Ys)]; ...`.

Comment: Hmmm....I thought we were supposed to avoid if-statements--and even case statements.  I think I've heard Francesco Cesarini say in a video that he helps *beginners* transform case statements into function clauses.  Here's what a style guide has to say:  https://github.com/inaka/erlang_guidelines#more-smaller-functions-over-case-expressions.  And here's an interesting read from Joe Armstrong on the matter: http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2009-December/048101.html

Comment: @7stud. Thanks for the links. Your comment is the only one which clearly answered my question. Since you only included this in a comment, I wrote up an answer referencing your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like this one:

```
inter(L1,L2) -> inter(lists:sort(L1),lists:sort(L2),[]).

inter([H1|T1],[H1|T2],Acc) -> inter(T1,T2,[H1|Acc]);
inter([H1|T1],[H2|T2],Acc) when H1 < H2 -> inter(T1,[H2|T2],Acc);
inter([H1|T1],[_|T2],Acc) -> inter([H1|T1],T2,Acc);
inter([],_,Acc) -> Acc;
inter(_,_,Acc) -> Acc.
```

it gives the exact intersection:

```
inter("abcd","efgh") -> []
inter("abcd","efagh") -> "a"
inter("abcd","efagah") -> "a"
inter("agbacd","eafagha") -> "aag"
```

if you want that a value appears only once, simply replace one of the `lists:sort/1` function by `lists:usort/1`

---

**Edit**

As @9000 says, one clause is useless:

```
inter(L1,L2) -> inter(lists:sort(L1),lists:sort(L2),[]).

inter([H1|T1],[H1|T2],Acc) -> inter(T1,T2,[H1|Acc]);
inter([H1|T1],[H2|T2],Acc) when H1 < H2 -> inter(T1,[H2|T2],Acc);
inter([H1|T1],[_|T2],Acc) -> inter([H1|T1],T2,Acc);
inter(_,_,Acc) -> Acc.
```

gives the same result, and

```
inter(L1,L2) -> inter(lists:usort(L1),lists:sort(L2),[]).

inter([H1|T1],[H1|T2],Acc) -> inter(T1,T2,[H1|Acc]);
inter([H1|T1],[H2|T2],Acc) when H1 < H2 -> inter(T1,[H2|T2],Acc);
inter([H1|T1],[_|T2],Acc) -> inter([H1|T1],T2,Acc);
inter(_,_,Acc) -> Acc.
```

removes any duplicate in the output.

If you know that there are no duplicate values in the input list, I think that

```
inter(L1,L2) -> [X || X <- L1, Y <- L2, X == Y].
```

is the shorter code solution but much slower (1 second to evaluate the intersection of 2 lists of 10 000 elements compare to 16ms for the previous solution, and an O(2) complexity comparable to @David Varela proposal; the ratio is 70s compare to 280ms with 2 lists of 100 000 elements!, an I guess there is a very high risk to run out of memory with bigger lists)

Comment: Aren't the two last patterns for `inter` equivalent to the last pattern?

Comment: BTW, if you use the ability to sort values (are all values comparable?), you can very cheaply leave only unique values in the sorted lists, and do away with any duplicates in the result, if the set semantics are assumed.

Comment: Yes the line `inter([],_,Acc) -> Acc;` is useless, I realized it 1 minute after being in bed :o).

Comment: In erlang you can compare any value, `>` is defined for all the types, and the type order is : `number < atom < reference < fun < port < pid < tuple < map < nil < list < bit string`.  To avoid duplicates simply change `inter(L1,L2) -> inter(lists:sort(L1),lists:sort(L2),[]).` to `inter(L1,L2) -> inter(lists:usort(L1),lists:sort(L2),[]).`

Answer (score 2):

The canonical way ("canonical" as in "SICP") is to use an accumulator.

```
myIntersection(A, B) -> myIntersectionInner(A, B, []).

myIntersectionInner([], _, Acc) -> Acc;
myIntersectionInner(_, [], Acc) -> Acc;
myIntersectionInner([A|As], B, Acc) -> 
  case myMember(A, Bs) of
    true -> 
      myIntersectionInner(As, Bs, [A|Acc]);
    false -> 
      myIntersectionInner(As, Bs, [Acc]);
  end.
```

This implementation of course produces duplicates if duplicates are present in both inputs. This can be fixed at the expense of calling `myMember(A, Acc)` and only appending `A` is the result is negative.

My apologies for the approximate syntax.

Comment: you can't use custom function in guards of `if ` expression. For it exist `case of`.

Comment: @Atomic_alarm: Thanks! Indeed, only some BIFs are allowed. I hope I've fixed my code by now (I don't have an Erlang installation handy to check).

Comment: this solution seems to have the inconvenient that is `Val` is present several times in list `A` but only one in list `B`, it will appear several times in the result.

Comment: @Pascal: Indeed, as mentioned in the answer. Also, it has O(|A| * |B|) time complexity; with the lookup required for uniqueness, it would be even worse. If data structures with a faster lookup, e.g. trees or hash tables, were used instead of plain lists, things would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Although I appreciate the efficient implementations suggested, my intention was to better understand Erlang's implementation. As a beginner, I think @7stud's comment, particularly http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2009-December/048101.html, was the most illuminating. In essence, 'case' and pattern matching in functions use the same mechanism under the hood, although functions should be preferred for clarity.

In a real system, I would go with one of @Pascal's implementations; depending on whether 'intersect' did any heavy lifting.