# How to write "a==b ? X : Y" in Erlang, in other words how to write a C-style ternary operator?

Tags: erlang, conditional-operator

Is there a good way to write code like this in Erlang?

```
A == B ? X : Y
```

below is ruby-style code. This is also known as a [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation#Computer_science).

Comment: You do realize that what you wrote is the same as `a == b`, right? Is that really what you're asking for, or is it something else?

Comment: @Gabe in C or a language which has a C-like syntax, sure. That's not valid erlang though :-)

Comment: All `if` statements in erlang are already an expression ... I'm not sure what the question is asking. Are you looking for something like `if cond -> true_expr; true -> false_expr; end`? There is also `case`, which may be more desirable, depending.

Comment: `a` and `b` are inequal atoms in erlang. You could just write this as `false`

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963918/how-to-achieve-if-else-in-erlang).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### Explanation

The reason the ternary operator `_ ? _ : _` exists in many languages is due to the fact that they have two syntactic classes: Statements and Expressions. Since if-then-else constructions usually belong the the statement-class, there is no way to get that working for when you are entering an expression. Hence you add the `_ ? _ : _` operator to the expression class.

As another post states, you can take `a == b ? true : false` and just write `a == b`, but that does not explain the general case where we may have `a == b ? X : Y` for arbitrary expressions `X` and `Y`. Also note that `a == b` is always `false` in Erlang, so you could argue that the real thing to do is to replace the whole expression with `false`.

Luckily, Erlang, as is the case for most functional languages, have one syntactic class only, expressions. Hence you can use `case a == b of X -> ...; Y -> ... end` in any place in a function, other expressions included. In other words, the ternary `_ ? _ : _` operator is redundant in Erlang since the `case` already works.

### An example:

Suppose we are to return a simple proplist and we have some computation we need to do

```
  f() ->
    case a == b of
          true -> 
           [{a, 3},
            {b, <<"YE">>},
            {c, 7}];
          false ->
           [{a, 3},
            {b, <<"YE">>},
            {c, "HELLO!!!"}];
    end.
```

But since the `case` construction is an expression, we can just inline it:

```
  f() ->
    [{a, 3},
     {b, <<"YE">>},
     {c, case a == b of
          true -> 7;
          false -> "HELLO!!!"
         end}].
```

and be done with the thing.

### Why I am not advocating the use of IF

the `if .. end` construction in Erlang is usually not what you want. You want to scrutinize a value `a == b` in this case and it can yield one of two outputs `true` or `false`. In that case the `case`-expression is more direct. The `if` is better used if you have to check for multiple different tests and pick the first matching, whereas we only have a single test to make here.

Comment: Just want to mention that in case of Ruby particularly using tertiary operator is mostly the matter of convenience. Compare `a = if false then "T" else "F" end` and `a = false ? "T" : "F"`. Both forms work.

Comment: "The reason the ternary operator _ ? _ : _ exists in many languages is due to the fact that they have two syntactic classes"

While that's true, the real reason I use it in languages that support it is because it is less verbose than other methods.  It's true that there's a difference between statements and expressions, and I understand the difference between the two, but my reasons for choosing to use `_?_:_` is always based on code clarity.

Answer (score 8):

We use macro like this:

```
-define(IF(Cond,E1,E2), (case (Cond) of true -> (E1); false -> (E2) end)).
```

Then in your code you write:

```
io:format("~s~n", [?IF(a==b, "equal", "not equal")]).
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're asking how to write something like `A == B ? X : Y` as an `if` expression, it's

```
if
    A == B ->
        X;
    true ->    % "true" means "else" here
        Y
end
```

You can also write it as a `case` expression:

```
case A == B of
    true ->
        X;
    _Else ->
        Y
end
```

or

```
case A == B of
    true ->
        X;
    false ->
        Y
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Since `a == b ? true : false` maps to `a == b`, you can use `a == b` in Erlang also.

Comment: For sake of clarity: to be valid erlang you'd need to make 'a' & 'b' upper case, i.e. variables.  Otherwise it'll compare the atoms 'a' and b'.  That match will always fail so the expression will always return false.

Comment: Thanks @sfinnie.  I do not really know erlang, so did not catch the case issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'if' like that

```
foo(A,B) ->
    [1,
     2,
     (if A == B -> 3; true -> 4 end), % A == B ? 3 : 4
     5,
     6].
```

special ?: form seems to be not necessary. You can of course use true/false as return value but I think you meant more general form, as that one would be useless (A == B does the same job).

Answer (score 0):

[@Gabe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6093004/1424877) is the most concise, and (as far as I can tell) idiomatic. The C expression `((A==B) ? X : Y)` maps directly to the Erlang expression

```
case A == B of
    true -> X;
    false -> Y
end
```

However, this *is* vastly more code than the C version. You should probably wrap it up into a convenience function — and someone should tell me if this already exists in the Erlang standard libraries!

```
iff(true, X, Y) -> X;
iff(false, X, Y) -> Y.
```

Then your C expression becomes simply `iff(A == B, X, Y)`. **However, beware!** that just like C, Erlang eagerly evaluates function arguments. If `X` or `Y` have side effects or are expensive to evaluate, then `iff` will not be equivalent to an in-line `case` expression.