# ejabberd 2.1.11 error on Erlang Module Hook

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I followed this article step by step and I seem to be the only person to get this specific error.
http://jasonrowe.com/2011/12/30/ejabberd-offline-messages/comment-page-1/#comment-2274

- I created and compiled the erlang code.
- I added the .beam file to the location specified.
- I updated the ejabberd.cfg file.

But when I send an offline message to the ejabberd server I get the following error in the log file:

---

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 2013-02-21 15:34:50 ===
E(<0.365.0>:ejabberd_hooks:294) : {if_clause,
                                      [{mod_http_offline,create_message,3},
                                       {ejabberd_hooks,run1,3},
                                       {ejabberd_sm,route,3},
                                       {ejabberd_local,route,3},
                                       {ejabberd_router,route,3},
                                       {ejabberd_c2s,session_established2,2},
                                       {p1_fsm,handle_msg,10},
                                       {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}
running hook: {offline_message_hook,
                  [{jid,"test","zspc-10","Spark 2.6.3","test","zspc-10",
                       "Spark 2.6.3"},
                   {jid,"johan","zspc-10",[],"johan","zspc-10",[]},
                   {xmlelement,"message",
                       [{"id","4z5S1-69"},{"to","johan@zspc-10"}],
                       [{xmlelement,"x",
                            [{"xmlns","jabber:x:event"}],
                            [{xmlelement,"composing",[],[]}]}]}]}
```

The error occurs in the `create_message` function.  Here is what it looks like:

```
create_message(_From, _To, Packet) ->
        Type = xml:get_tag_attr_s("type", Packet),
        FromS = xml:get_tag_attr_s("from", Packet),
        ToS = xml:get_tag_attr_s("to", Packet),
        Body = xml:get_path_s(Packet, [{elem, "body"}, cdata]),
        if (Type == "chat") ->
            post_offline_message(FromS, ToS, Body)
        end.
```

If it's any help, I'm running ejabberd 2.1.11 on a Windows 7 pc and compiled the code with erlang R14B04.

Comment: Is it worth opening this Question again, since legoscia has edit it to adhere to the guidelines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the relevant piece of code from that blog post:

```
create_message(_From, _To, Packet) ->
        Type = xml:get_tag_attr_s("type", Packet),
        FromS = xml:get_tag_attr_s("from", Packet),
        ToS = xml:get_tag_attr_s("to", Packet),
        Body = xml:get_path_s(Packet, [{elem, "body"}, cdata]),
        if (Type == "chat") ->
            post_offline_message(FromS, ToS, Body)
        end.
```

You're getting an `if_clause` error, which means that no clause of the `if` expression was true.  Erlang, unlike many other languages, *requires* that at least one of the conditions be true, otherwise you'll get a runtime error like this.

So the question is what the code should do when `Type` is not `"chat"`.  If it should just do nothing, add a `true` clause:

```
        if (Type == "chat") ->
            post_offline_message(FromS, ToS, Body);
          true ->
            ok
        end.
```

Or even better, rewrite it as a `case` expression.  In Erlang, `case` expressions are much more common than `if` expressions.

```
        case Type of
          "chat" ->
            post_offline_message(FromS, ToS, Body);
          _ ->
            ok
        end.
```

That is, if `Type` matches `"chat"`, evaluate the first clause, and otherwise, if it matches `_` (a wildcard match), evaluate the second clause.  See also the examples in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/963918/113848).